# What is the correct way to save Hibernate JPA child entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, save, entity, parent-child

I can for the life of me just not get my head around this.

We generated standard Entity objects using Intellij.
I am now trying to save a parent child relationship.

I have 2 tables, event_person_register and event_user_role. This is what I have tried.

```
eventPersonRegister.setEventUserRolesByPersonRegisterId(new ArrayList<>());

EventUserRole eventUserRole = new EventUserRole();
eventUserRole.setEventPersonRegisterByUserRoleLinkPersonId(eventPersonRegister);
eventUserRole.setUserRole("ROLE_USER");
eventPersonRegister.getEventUserRolesByPersonRegisterId().add(eventUserRole);

eventPersonRegisterRepository.save(eventPersonRegister);
```

Only the parent is saved to the DB and not the child record.
I have not placed any Cascade or fetch types on the OneToMany annotation. One registered person can have multiple roles.

**Update 1:**

I have tried the following from the eventPersonRegister entity:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "eventPersonRegisterByUserRoleLinkPersonId", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

But get error:

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

If I try from the user_role side, then I don't get any errors, but only the parent is saved and not the child.

Comment: You actually answered the question: _"I have not placed any Cascade or fetch types on the OneToMany annotation."_ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you can use cascade on the OneToMany side.

If you don't want to use cascade, the other option is to:

```
//persist eventPersonRegister
eventPersonRegister.setEventUserRolesByPersonRegisterId(new ArrayList<>());
entityManager.persist(eventPersonRegister); 

//persist eventUserRole
EventUserRole eventUserRole = new EventUserRole();
eventUserRole.setUserRole("ROLE_USER");
entityManager.persist(eventUserRole);

//set the relation between eventUserRole and eventPersonRegister
eventUserRole.setEventPersonRegisterByUserRoleLinkPersonId(eventPersonRegister);  
eventPersonRegister.getEventUserRolesByPersonRegisterId().add(eventUserRole);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly as above and it's working 100%. I also followed some of this which helped a lot:
[hibernate one to many mapping annotation](http://www.journaldev.com/2924/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-annotation)